# Will GSC show a 404 error if the 404 page is HTTP but rest of site is HTTPS?

Tags: google-search-console

As well as the URL being requested being HTTPS.

- 404 page is HTTP (rest of domain the same)
- Requested page is HTTPS
- Website is HTTPS
- GSC is set up as HTTPS

Comment: This is possible and very likely if the site was previously or currently served as HTTP or a link to the site exists as HTTP, etc. This does happen. The site should redirect HTTP to HTTPS if you intend to only server it as HTTPS. Otherwise you will need a canonical tag from your HTTP pages to your identical HTTPS pages to avoid duplicate content issues. Cheers!!

Comment: Not sure that I understand? If the entire site is HTTPS, and the request is for HTTPS then how are you serving the 404 over plain old HTTP? Are you _redirecting_ to the error document?!

Comment: @w3dk Yes, 301 to 404 (this is a clients site....)

closetnoc sorry, wasn't fully clear. I'm not talking about general 404s post migration. I'm talking about this specific set-up and a user requests a random page which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think GSC will show a 404 error on the "HTTPS property" if the page that is returning the 404 is served over HTTP. Although maybe it will be seen as a soft-404? (You would need to verify the "HTTP property" in GSC as well in order to see an HTTP 404 reported.)

> Are you redirecting to the error document?! Yes, 301 to 404

However, if you are *redirecting* the non-existent HTTPS URL then there is no 404 - it's a 301. Only the error document URL itself is returning a 404, so it's the "error document" that doesn't exist, not the URL that is being requested initially. (I would guess that Google is likely to treat the HTTPS URL as a soft-404 in this instance, but that is an assumption, not a general rule.)

Comment: That sounds about right to me. It is a 301 to the HTTP path initially attempted on HTTPS then 404 on HTTP. We've got GSC set up for both properties. I think you're right it will show soft 404's - not ideal.